Molecular Docking - a guide
I have a question regarding molecular docking, as I am far for familiar with it.
I started with generating the models of a ligand (which is a F(ab) part of an antibody).
I obtained the structure of a receptor from the Protein Databank.
Using two tools, LightDock and PyDockWEB, I have obtained docking models. The options I included, were the restraints - as for the antibodies, there are regions (CDRs) that will be most likely in contact with a receptor.
However, the best-score docking models are different for the two tools and alternatives using the same tool. There is contact with receptor in many regions, some of which are in agreement in the different cases, but others differ.
How do I choose the one that is most probable, except by using the score returned by the tool? What else can I do? Are there any additional steps that I could take to make sure that a chosen model is also probable?
Additionally, I am not sure if the antibody model is correct. It is stated to be a best model, but it has not been refined. What tools should I use to relax, minimize energy and so on? I used the model straight from the modelling software, without altering the options.
I have tried to go through the procedure by consulting the available information, but I feel lost and would like to find a guide to this topic.

Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] so as to find out about this site, and, in particular, the Help on asking good questions. You will see that we deal with one question at a time, whereas you are asking many questions or asking to be pointed to a general book or article. In addition I would  point out that the tools you mention are quite specialized, and only few biologist on this list are likely to be familiar with them. Have you tried to see if there are user groups or mailing lists associate with the software?
